# SQL Server Express 2008 originally installed and then upgraded SQL Server Management 2008 - but no profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008

Originally I had two instances of SQL Server Express 2008 installed on my machine, IT then removed these so that they could upgrade me to SQL Server Management 2008 (with the aim that I would have profiler). My two original instances are there, however under tools there is no profiler. Should the IT guy installed a third instance so that I would have profiler? Or done something different.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to ensure is that you don't have a whole new SQL Server path under your All Programs folder.  I don't recall if SQL Server Express and SQL Server create separate paths in All Programs.  Also, look for Profiler under the Performance Tools folder in your SQL Server programs folder.

Check to see if you have the executable on your computer.  By default, the Profiler executable is installed in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn`.  It's called PROFILER.EXE.

Finally, if you still can't find Profiler, run the installer again and do a custom install.  Make sure the tools are included for install, which is not the default install normally.

Comment: I had looked for that folder under my programs folder but there was no profiler. On Monday I shall check that executable is installed. The guy who did the install said that the install would not allow him to access that bit...which is why I think I don't have profiler. However he says he did the same install on my PC that he did on two other users and they have profiler working.